# Find documents matching a condition depending on another document value

Tags: mongodb

My collection contains the following documents:

```
{
  "_id": "a",
  "index": 1
},
{
  "_id": "b",
  "index": 2
},
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 3
},
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 4
}
```

Given an id, I would like to find all the documents having a greater index that the index corresponding to the id.

For example, if `id="b"`, then `index=2` and result would be

```
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 3
},
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 4
}
```

I thougt I could use an aggregation pipeline and use `$add_field` to add searched index into each document and the use a `$match`, but cannot find how to do it. I mean, my problem would be solved if I cold produce this result:

```
{
  "_id": "a",
  "index": 1,
  "ref_index": 2
},
{
  "_id": "b",
  "index": 2,
  "ref_index": 2
},
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 3,
  "ref_index": 2
},
{
  "_id": "c",
  "index": 4,
  "ref_index": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure is there any straight way to handle this operation, you  need to do 2 queries or you can try below aggregation pipeline,

- `$facet` to separate results, `getIndex` to get matching document of `_id: "b"`, `allDocs` to get all documents
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `allDocs` and filter document by index greater than condition
- `$unwind` deconstruct `allDocs` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `allDocs` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      getIndex: [{ $match: { _id: "b" } }],
      allDocs: [{ $match: {} }]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      allDocs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$allDocs",
          cond: {
            $gt: [
              "$$this.index",
              { $first: "$getIndex.index" }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$allDocs" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$allDocs" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MdUXBisWM_z)